# Getting data to $scope fails in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass data to `$scope.post` by doing it this way, but it doesn't want to work like I imagine it to do. I get no errors in the console and the code is inside the PostController.

```
var PostController = function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, $http, Post, User) {
    $scope.post = {};
    $scope.getById = function (id) {
        return $http.get('/api/Post/' + id).success(function (data) {
            $scope.post = data;
        });
    }
        $scope.getById($routeParams.id);
        console.log($scope.post);
}
```

Here's the routing too:

```
when('/post/:id', { controller: PostController, templateUrl: 'post.html' }).
```

Edit, whole PostController added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getById` is an async call, it's not failing, you're just not waiting! Use `.then` to return  a promise and do the assignment in the callback:

```
$scope.getById = function (id) {
    return $http.get('/api/Post/' + id).then(function (result) {
         return result.data
    });
}

$scope.getById($routeParams.id).then(function(data) {
    $scope.post = data;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`console.log($scope.post);` is called before callback, so there is no values.if you want to get the value in console, try this..

```
$scope.getById = function (id) {
        return $http.get('/api/Post/' + id).success(function (data) {
            $scope.post = data;
            console.log($scope.post);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

$http get returns **promise**. 
That means, that function inside success, isn't invoked at once. 
It's not intuitive, but that is how promises work. 
To track resulting data, insert console.log inside success function

```
return $http.get('/api/Post/' + id).success(function (data) {
            $scope.post = data;
            console.log('$scope post: ',$scope.post);
        });
```

You will see data returned from get call to debug ( you can also print this variable in your view ).

How it works:

$http.get returns a promise, and also adds addtional success and error function.

After $http.get, you chain promise to success function

```
$http.get('/api/Post/' + id).success
```

which is called after successful server response ( http codes from 200 to 299 ), and error function is called where there is failure ( 400 - 499 codes ).

Answer (score 0):

The first two answers are probably the solution to your problem... since your `console.log` is executing before the callback to the HTTP request. However, it is good practice to also handle HTTP errors, which could always be a problem. Here is an example of how you would do that:

```
$http.get('/api/Post/' + id).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //handle success
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //handle error
  });
```